# Why is my lambda function not able to consume messages sent by SQS in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am using AWS Lambda function to consume the messages received on AWS SQS. The lambda function will further call my service but for now, I was trying to get the messages sent on SQS queue. I have made a standard queue in SQS and a Lambda function in Java. I made a new lambda project in my Eclipse IDE and this is my function:

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
        return (String) input;
    }
}
```

The file does not show any error. I exported the project as .jar file and uploaded the jar file to my lambda function. I have also specified the handler in my lambda function (packageName.className). If I test the lambda function it executed fine but when I send a message to SQS, it increments the no of messages in `message flight` which I have read are the messages not consumed by the consumer which is lambda in my case. [image]

[image]
[image]

Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Have you checked CloudWatch logs for the lambd? The messages are in flight as your lambda probably is erroring out.

Comment: @Marcin It does not show anything on the CloudWatch. `No Log Groups To Show`.

Comment: So your lambda does not have permissions for CW. Add them, and you should see it log group.

Comment: See my edit. I had these 2 permissions. Is there any other permission that needs to be added? @Marcin The 3 actions are from previous function which I created but then I deleted it from logs when I made this function. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: So send more sqs messages. If your lambda has CW permissions, the log group should be recreated for new invocations of your function.

Comment: When I test mt lambda function directly in aws lambda, it says `Execution result: succeeded(logs)`. But when I open `logs`, it says `There was an error loading Log Streams. Please try again by refreshing this page` on `CloudWatch > Log Groups > Streams for /aws/lambda/test4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209764/discussion-between-shashank-gupta-and-marcin).

Comment: Sorry, cant do chat now.

Comment: It's okay. Do you know any solution to my above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does not deserialize Strings and so when I used Map as an input, it worked fine.

```
public String handleRequest(Map<String,Object> input, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("Your Input is: " +input);
    System.out.println(input);
    return  "Executed Successfully";
}
```

I read this from [Lionel Port's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545642/error-executing-hello-world-for-aws-lambda-in-java). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

take SQSEvent event as a parameter with will connect your aws SQS with Java. Than you can get the messages using SQSMessage class and see your messages. see the below codes:

```java
public String handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context){
    for(SQSMessage msg : event.getRecords()){
        System.out.println(msg.getBody());
        System.out.println("MSG" + msg.getBody());
    }
}
```